# How can I take a dataframe and split it into individual lists by column?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, anaconda

As the question says, I have a data frame which is quite large but looks like:

```
        ID    Count    ValueX    Value 2    Value 3
RowX    1      234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    1      123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    1      234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    1      123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    1      234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    1      123.     165.       543.      342
RowX    2      234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    2      123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    2      234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    2      123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    2      234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    2      123.     165.       543.      342
.
.
.
RowX    1233   234.     255.       yes.      yes
RowY    1233   123.     135.       543.      342
RowW    1233   234.     235.       yes.      yes
RowJ    1233   123.     115.       543.      342
RowA    1233   234.     285.       yes.      yes
RowR    1233   123.     165.       543.      342
```

What I want is to be able to take the df and split it into lists by column, so that I end up with lists for `ID`, `Count`, `ValueX`, `Value 2` and the rest of it. Currently, I'm doing it like:

```
IDlist = df_original.ID.tolist()
Countlist = df_original.Count.tolist()
...
```

This gives me the solution I need, but I want to know if there is a shorter way of splitting the df into lists.

Comment: When you say "shorter" do you mean shorter lines of code?  Or do you want a loop that makes a list of lists?

Comment: Either really, right now I'm manually creating 33 lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create nested lists:

```
L = df.values.T.tolist()

print (L)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0],
 [255.0, 135.0, 235.0, 115.0, 285.0, 165.0, 255.0, 135.0, 235.0, 115.0, 285.0, 165.0], 
 ['yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.','yes.','543.','yes.','543.','yes.','543.'],
 ['yes', '342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342']]
```

You can access by position like:

```
print (L[0])
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Or better create dictionary of `list`s:

```
d = df.to_dict('l')
print (d)
{
'Count':[234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0, 234.0, 123.0],
'Value 3':['yes', '342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342','yes','342', 'yes', '342', 'yes', '342'],
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
'Value 2': ['yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.', 
            'yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.', 'yes.', '543.'], 
'ValueX':[255.0, 135.0, 235.0, 115.0, 285.0, 165.0, 255.0, 135.0, 235.0, 115.0, 285.0,165.0]
}
```

You can access by column name like:

```
print (d['ID'])
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Can you go a bit more into what this does?

Comment: Ok, only question is do you need nested lists? Or not?

Comment: I don't really need nested lists, no

Comment: I think second solution is better.

Comment: Thank you so much!